# Replace time part with custom time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have a scenario where I have to match the system time, but I have to match the current time with a pre-set saved datetime variable in sql server.

```
DECLARE @SyncDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @SystemDate AS DATETIME
SELECT  @SyncDate = dbo.TimeTable.auto_time    
FROM    dbo.TimeTable
'1900-01-01 03:00
SELECT  @SystemDate = GETDATE()
```

I have to replace the `@SyncDate` with current date and already saved time, i.e:

```
2015-11-16 03:00
```

Any body can help?

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Comment: sql-server 2008, 2005

Comment: Try this: `SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(@SyncDate AS TIME)`

Comment: @FelixPamittan: this will work in SQL Server **2008** and newer - but it will *fail* in 2005, since `DATE` and `TIME` are not known types in 2005 (they were introdued in 2008 only)

Comment: @marc_s, Yup. I added an answer below that works for 2005.

Comment: Hi, Its not working for SQL Server 2005 Version

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add a `TIME` value to a `DATETIME` value in SQL Server 2008+. But for SQL Server 2005, you can use `DATETIME` operations such as `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

For SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @SyncDate DATETIME = CAST('1900-01-01 03:00' AS DATETIME)

SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(@SyncDate AS TIME)
```

For SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @SyncDate DATETIME 
SET @SyncDate = CAST('1900-01-01 03:00' AS DATETIME)

SELECT 
    DATEADD(
        MILLISECOND, 
        DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST(@SyncDate AS DATE), @SyncDate), 
        CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean not working. Make sure to remove the SQL Server 2008 version when running it in 2005. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
DECLARE @SyncDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @SystemDate AS DATETIME = '1900-01-01 03:00' --saved time

SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',CAST(@SyncDate AS DATE)), CAST(CAST(@SystemDate AS TIME) AS DATETIME));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392641)**</kbd>

Output:

```
2015-11-16 03:00:00
```

If saved time is always in `1900-01-01 hh:mm:ss` format you can use:

```
DECLARE @SyncDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @SystemDate AS DATETIME = '1900-01-01 03:00'

SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',CAST(@SyncDate AS DATE)), @SystemDate);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392639)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have done with a generic query, that is free form version check or version dependency.

```
DECLARE @SyncDate AS DATETIME = '1900-01-01 03:00'
DECLARE @SystemDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE() ;

SELECT  @SyncDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @SystemDate))
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @SyncDate, 108)
SELECT  @SyncDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are here in 2020, for SqlServer 2016:

```
DECLARE @SyncDate DATETIME = CAST('1900-01-01 03:00' AS DATETIME)

SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(@SyncDate AS DATETIME)
```

Output

```
2020-11-26 03:00:00.0
```

PS: Query was ran on 26-Nov-2020.